# How do I print the pointer value of a Go object? What does the pointer value mean?

Tags: go

I am just playing around with Go and do not yet have a good mental model of when structs are passed by value or by reference.

This may be a very dumb question but I just want to experiment a bit and see if I am still working on the same object or I have made a copy of it (passed it by value).

Is there a way to print the pointer (or internal id if pointer value is changed by gc) of an object?

```
package main

import ( "runtime" )

type Something struct {
    number int
    queue chan int
}

func gotest( s *Something, done chan bool ) {
    println( "from gotest:")
    println( &s )
    for num := range s.queue {
        println( num )
        s.number = num
    }
    done <- true
}

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(4)
    s := new(Something)
    println(&s)
    s.queue = make(chan int)
    done := make(chan bool)
    go gotest(s, done)
    s.queue <- 42
    close(s.queue)
    <- done
    println(&s)
    println(s.number)
}
```

gives on my windows (8g compiled version):

```
0x4930d4
from gotest:
0x4974d8
42
0x4930d4
42
```

Why does the pointer value from within the go routine show a different value? The quantity on the original object did get changed so it was working with the same object. Is there a way to see an object id that is persistent?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Go function arguments are passed by value.

First, let's discard the irrelevant parts of your example, so that we can easily see that you are merely passing an argument by value. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func byval(q *int) {
    fmt.Printf("3. byval -- q %T: &q=%p q=&i=%p  *q=i=%v\n", q, &q, q, *q)
    *q = 4143
    fmt.Printf("4. byval -- q %T: &q=%p q=&i=%p  *q=i=%v\n", q, &q, q, *q)
    q = nil
}

func main() {
    i := int(42)
    fmt.Printf("1. main  -- i  %T: &i=%p i=%v\n", i, &i, i)
    p := &i
    fmt.Printf("2. main  -- p %T: &p=%p p=&i=%p  *p=i=%v\n", p, &p, p, *p)
    byval(p)
    fmt.Printf("5. main  -- p %T: &p=%p p=&i=%p  *p=i=%v\n", p, &p, p, *p)
    fmt.Printf("6. main  -- i  %T: &i=%p i=%v\n", i, &i, i)
}
```

Output:

```
1. main  -- i  int: &i=0xf840000040 i=42
2. main  -- p *int: &p=0xf8400000f0 p=&i=0xf840000040  *p=i=42
3. byval -- q *int: &q=0xf8400000d8 q=&i=0xf840000040  *q=i=42
4. byval -- q *int: &q=0xf8400000d8 q=&i=0xf840000040  *q=i=4143
5. main  -- p *int: &p=0xf8400000f0 p=&i=0xf840000040  *p=i=4143
6. main  -- i  int: &i=0xf840000040 i=4143
```

In function `main`, `i` is an `int` variable at memory location (`&i`) `0xf800000040` with an initial value (`i`) `42`.

In function `main`, `p` is a pointer to an `int` variable at memory location (`&p`) `0xf8000000f0` with a value (`p`=`&i`) `0xf800000040` which points to an `int` value (`*p`=`i`) `42`.

In function `main`, `byval(p)` is a function call which assigns the value (`p`=`&i`) `0xf800000040` of the argument at memory location (`&p`) `0xf8000000f0` to the function `byval` parameter `q` at memory location (`&q`) `0xf8000000d8`. In other words, memory is allocated for the `byval` parameter `q` and the value of the `main` `byval` argument `p` is assigned to it; the values of `p` and `q` are initially the same, but the variables `p` and `q` are distinct.

In function `byval`, using pointer `q` (`*int`), which is a copy of pointer `p` (`*int`), integer `*q` (`i`) is set to a new int value `4143`. At the end before returning. the pointer `q` is set to `nil` (zero value), which has no effect on `p` since `q` is a copy.

In function `main`, `p` is a pointer to an `int` variable at memory location (`&p`) `0xf8000000f0` with a value (`p`=`&i`) `0xf800000040` which points to a new `int` value (`*p`=`i`) `4143`.

In function `main`, `i` is an `int` variable at memory location (`&i`) `0xf800000040` with a final value (`i`) `4143`.

In your example, the function `main` variable `s` used as an argument to the function `gotest` call is not the same as the function `gotest` parameter `s`. They have the same name, but are different variables with different scopes and memory locations. The function parameter `s` hides the function call argument `s`. That's why in my example, I named the argument and parameter variables `p` and `q` respectively to emphasize the difference.

In your example, (`&s`) `0x4930d4` is the address of the memory location for the variable `s` in function `main` that is used as an argument to the function call `gotest(s, done)`, and `0x4974d8` is the address of the memory location for the function `gotest` parameter `s`. If you set parameter `s = nil` at the end of function `gotest`, it has no effect on variable `s` in `main`; `s` in `main` and `s` in `gotest` are distinct memory locations. In terms of types, `&s` is `**Something`, `s` is `*Something`, and `*s` is `Something`. `&s` is a pointer to (address of memory location) `s`, which is a pointer to (address of memory location) an anonymous variable of type `Something`. In terms of values, `main.&s != gotest.&s`, `main.s == gotest.s`, `main.*s == gotest.*s`, and `main.s.number == gotest.s.number`.

You should take mkb's sage advice and stop using `println(&s)`. Use the `fmt` package, for example,

```
fmt.Printf("%v %p %v\n", &s, s, *s)
```

Pointers have the same value when they point to the same memory location; pointers have different values when they point to different memory locations.

Comment: In my example the gotest takes an pointer to 'Something' so I am assuming it to be referring to the same object and it clearly is since after I change the value inside the go-routine the object also has its value changed in the main function. The pointer value printed is different.

Comment: @JamesDean In your example, you are printing pointer value &s type **Something, which is not the same as pointer value s type *Something. I've revised my example to pass a pointer by value.

Comment: @James Dean You printed out the address of the pointer (i.e. a pointer to the `s` pointer), - pointers are passed by value, the address of `s` is not the same as `s`. If your gotest function did `println( s )` intead, it'd print he pointer value.

Comment: Oh now I see what is going on. By doing println(&s) I was printing the address of the pointer instead of the pointer value. If I had done println(s) it would have show the same pointer in the main and the go routine function.

Comment: @JamesDean Exactly. In Go as in C, for s *Something, it's essential to know the difference between &s, s and *s.

Answer (score 13):

In Go, arguments are passed by value.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type SomeStruct struct {
    e int
}

// struct passed by value
func v(v SomeStruct) {
    fmt.Printf("v: %p %v\n", &v, v)
    v.e = 2
    fmt.Printf("v: %p %v\n", &v, v)
}

// pointer to struct passed by value
func p(p *SomeStruct) {
    fmt.Printf("p: %p %v\n", p, *p)
    p.e = 2
    fmt.Printf("p: %p %v\n", p, *p)
}

func main() {
    var s SomeStruct
    s.e = 1
    fmt.Printf("s: %p %v\n", &s, s)
    v(s)
    fmt.Printf("s: %p %v\n", &s, s)
    p(&s)
    fmt.Printf("s: %p %v\n", &s, s)
}
```

Output:

```
s: 0xf800000040 {1}
v: 0xf8000000e0 {1}
v: 0xf8000000e0 {2}
s: 0xf800000040 {1}
p: 0xf800000040 {1}
p: 0xf800000040 {2}
s: 0xf800000040 {2}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
type sometype struct { }
a := sometype {}
b := int(2)
println("Ptr to a", &a)
println("Ptr to b", &b)
```

Comment: You shouldn't use the builtin println but use something appropriate from the fmt package: http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Bootstrapping

Answer (score 1):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func zeroval(ival int) {
     ival = 0
}

func zeroptr(iptr *int) {
     *iptr = 0
}

func main() {
    i := 1
    fmt.Println("initial:", i)
    zeroval(i)
    fmt.Println("zeroval:", i)
    //The &i syntax gives the memory address of i, i.e. a pointer to i.
    zeroptr(&i)
    fmt.Println("zeroptr:", i)
    //Pointers can be printed too.
    fmt.Println("pointer:", &i)
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
$ go run pointers.go
initial: 1
zeroval: 1
zeroptr: 0
pointer: 0x42131100
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do I [print](https://play.golang.org/p/RUyb95X7rT) the pointer value of a Go object?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a := 42
    fmt.Println(&a)
}
```

results in:

```
0x1040a124
```

> What does the pointer value mean?

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)):

> A pointer references a location in memory