# How to convert memory address (like 0xc20803a000) to string? Golang

Tags: memory, go

I think question is quite self-explained. I want to know how can I convert memory address like this `0xc20803a000` to string type. Is it possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [fmt.Sprintf()](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf), with %p (base 16 notation, with leading 0x)

```
myString := fmt.Sprintf("%p", yourPointer)
```

`fmt.Sprintf()` returns a string.

You can see several examples (of printing a memory pointer) in:

- "[How do I print the pointer value of a Go object? What does the pointer value mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4963935/6309)".
- "[Go by Example: String Formatting](https://gobyexample.com/string-formatting)".

Replace in those examples `Printf` by `Sprintf`, and you have a string for you to use.